# return outside function

Tags: python, biopython

Hii I am getting the following error in Biopython: 'return' outside function (filename.. line 26)
Below is the code of myfile
PLEASE HELP

```
# File Name RandonProteinSequences.py
# standard library
import os
import random

# biopython
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
import Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta
from Bio import SeqIO
from sys import *

residueList1 = ["C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
residueList2 = ["A","K","L","M","N","S"]
residueList3 = ["P","Q","R","T","V","W","Y"]
residueList4 = ["C","A","G","U"]
def getProteinSeqRecord(residue, seqcount):
    strSeq = ""
for i in range(0,100,1):
    index = random.randint(0, len(residue)-1)
    strSeq += residue[index]

sequence = Seq(strSeq, IUPAC.IUPACProtein)
seqRec = SeqRecord(sequence, id = 'randSeq' + str(seqcount), description= 'A random sequence using Amino acid residues.')
return seqRec

def getProteinSequence(residue):
    strSeq = ""
for i in range(0,100,1):
    index = random.randint(0, len(residue)-1)
strSeq += residue[index]

sequence = Seq(strSeq, IUPAC.IUPACProtein)
return sequence

def randomProteinSeqRecord(index):
    if(index%2)==0:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList1, index)
    elif(index%3)==0:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList2, index)
    else:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList3, index)

#information
print '--- This is python based program to generate random sequences ---'
print '--- Provide number of random sequences to generate. Default 10 ---'
print '--- Inorder to save to a file provide file path or filename ---'
print '--- If none or invalid filepath is provided then results will be displayed to console ---'
print '--- The file will be created in fasta format ---'
print

filepathProvided = False
#raw_input received the user input as string
try:
    filepath = raw_input('Enter filepath to save sequences ... ')
    filepath = filepath + '.fasta'
    handle = open(filepath, "w")
    handle.close()

    filepathProvided = True
except IOError:
    print 'Invalid or No File provided will print results to console'
print
ranSeqCount = 10
try:
    ranSeqCount = int(raw_input('Enter number of random sequences to generate ... '))
except ValueError:
    ranSeqCount = 10
pass

if(filepathProvided):
    handle = open(filepath, "w")

if(filepathProvided):
    fasta_writer = Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta.WriteFasta(handle)
else:
    fasta_writer = Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta.WriteFasta(stdout)
print 'Sequence Count : '
print ranSeqCount

for i in range(0,ranSeqCount,1):
    fasta_writer.write(randomProteinSeqRecord(i+1))
if(filepathProvided):
    handle.close()
print 'File created at : ' + filepath

print
raw_input('Press any key to exit ...')
print
```

Comment: looks like you copy&pasted wrong

Comment: Despite the fact that the question poster could have obviously done SOME research to find the solution, I think this question doesn't deserve down-voting, as it can be very useful to python newcomers. The whole whitespace issue, combined with formatting loss on copy pasting from/to various sources can be very confusing

Comment: Indeed. I neither voted down nor voted for close. But I don't feel like I want to give a serious answer, as the OP obviously didn't spent much time on learning the basics of python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python is sensitive to indentation. If your code is badly indented, it won't work.

My amazing googling powers tell me you've taken your code from [this page](http://souvenirs-of-life.blogspot.com/2010/05/generation-of-random-amino-acid-protein.html), where unfortunately the code isn't properly formatted either.

But here, I took the effort. I'm not responsible if this will fail miserably though, because I didn't run it, not even mentally.

```
# File Name RandonProteinSequences.py
# standard library
import os
import random

# biopython
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
import Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta
from Bio import SeqIO
from sys import *

residueList1 = ["C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
residueList2 = ["A","K","L","M","N","S"]
residueList3 = ["P","Q","R","T","V","W","Y"]
residueList4 = ["C","A","G","U"]
def getProteinSeqRecord(residue, seqcount):
    strSeq = ""
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        index = random.randint(0, len(residue)-1)
        strSeq += residue[index]

    sequence = Seq(strSeq, IUPAC.IUPACProtein)
    seqRec = SeqRecord(sequence, id = 'randSeq' + str(seqcount), description= 'A random sequence using Amino acid residues.')
    return seqRec

def getProteinSequence(residue):
    strSeq = ""
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        index = random.randint(0, len(residue)-1)
        strSeq += residue[index]

    sequence = Seq(strSeq, IUPAC.IUPACProtein)
    return sequence

def randomProteinSeqRecord(index):
    if(index%2)==0:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList1, index)
    elif(index%3)==0:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList2, index)
    else:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList3, index)

#information
print '--- This is python based program to generate random sequences ---'
print '--- Provide number of random sequences to generate. Default 10 ---'
print '--- Inorder to save to a file provide file path or filename ---'
print '--- If none or invalid filepath is provided then results will be displayed to console ---'
print '--- The file will be created in fasta format ---'
print

filepathProvided = False
#raw_input received the user input as string
try:
    filepath = raw_input('Enter filepath to save sequences ... ')
    filepath = filepath + '.fasta'
    handle = open(filepath, "w")
    handle.close()

    filepathProvided = True
except IOError:
    print 'Invalid or No File provided will print results to console'
print
ranSeqCount = 10
try:
    ranSeqCount = int(raw_input('Enter number of random sequences to generate ... '))
except ValueError:
    ranSeqCount = 10
pass

if(filepathProvided):
    handle = open(filepath, "w")

if(filepathProvided):
    fasta_writer = Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta.WriteFasta(handle)
else:
    fasta_writer = Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta.WriteFasta(stdout)
print 'Sequence Count : '
print ranSeqCount

for i in range(0,ranSeqCount,1):
    fasta_writer.write(randomProteinSeqRecord(i+1))
if(filepathProvided):
    handle.close()
print 'File created at : ' + filepath

print
raw_input('Press any key to exit ...')
print
```

Comment: +1 for your amazing googling powers :)

Comment: THANKS....This worked... Although now it says that No module named writers.SeqRecord.fasta From where can I download this module...Acutally I am very weak in Python

Comment: @Hemant0285 [This page](http://python-biopython.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.49-1ubuntu1/namespaceBio_1_1writers_1_1SeqRecord_1_1fasta.html) says it was unused, undocumented, deprecated. This means it probably got removed in the meantime. I'm afraid this code you found must be quite old and needs to be updated.

Answer (score 5):

Python depends on indentation to determine where functions (and other block structures) end. Presumably, the function that is causing your error should look like this:

```
def getProteinSeqRecord(residue, seqcount):
    strSeq = ""
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        index = random.randint(0, len(residue)-1)
        strSeq += residue[index]

    sequence = Seq(strSeq, IUPAC.IUPACProtein)
    seqRec = SeqRecord(sequence, id = 'randSeq' + str(seqcount), description= 'A random sequence using Amino acid residues.')
    return seqRec
```

Comment: This worked.... Now it showed the same error at Line 35....Thanks for the above corrected//indented code....

Comment: Worked out the same thing at line 35...It works well.. jus the module missing error which I have mentioned below

Answer (score 2):

You have your intendation wrong

Comment: This answer is totally right, although not verbose. So it shouldn't be voted down.

Comment: Getting this error:: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hemant\Desktop\RandonProteinSequences.py", line 10, in <module>
    import Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta
ImportError: No module named writers.SeqRecord.fasta

Comment: @vikingosegundo: "totally right" and "useful" are two different things. Telling the person there is a whitespace mistake somewhere between the first line and the last line is virtually useless, especially to a beginner.

Comment: with the information, that the indention is wrong, the OP has enough to look on python.org, google and SO. So this is not a useless answer.

Comment: Brothers,, please lets not discuss who is right and who is wrong,,, Instead please help me ... with this error 

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Hemant\Desktop\RandonProteinSequences.py", line 10, in <module> import Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta ImportError: No module named writers.SeqRecord.fasta

Comment: @Hemant0285 [Check out my answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062423/importerror-no-module-named-writers-seqrecord-fasta/6090918#6090918).

Comment: Thanks Zecc... It worked... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062423/importerror-no-module-named-writers-seqrecord-fasta)