# ImportError: No module named writers.SeqRecord.fasta

Tags: python, biopython

```
# File Name RandonProteinSequences.py
# standard library
import os
import random

# biopython
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
import Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta
from Bio import SeqIO
from sys import *

residueList1 = ["C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
residueList2 = ["A","K","L","M","N","S"]
residueList3 = ["P","Q","R","T","V","W","Y"]
residueList4 = ["C","A","G","U"]
def getProteinSeqRecord(residue, seqcount):
    strSeq = ""
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        index = random.randint(0, len(residue)-1)
        strSeq += residue[index]

    sequence = Seq(strSeq, IUPAC.IUPACProtein)
    seqRec = SeqRecord(sequence, id = 'randSeq' + str(seqcount), description= 'A random sequence using Amino acid residues.')
    return seqRec

def getProteinSequence(residue):
    strSeq = ""
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        index = random.randint(0, len(residue)-1)
        strSeq += residue[index]

    sequence = Seq(strSeq, IUPAC.IUPACProtein)
    return sequence

def randomProteinSeqRecord(index):
    if(index%2)==0:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList1, index)
    elif(index%3)==0:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList2, index)
    else:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList3, index)

#information
print '--- This is python based program to generate random sequences ---'
print '--- Provide number of random sequences to generate. Default 10 ---'
print '--- Inorder to save to a file provide file path or filename ---'
print '--- If none or invalid filepath is provided then results will be displayed to console ---'
print '--- The file will be created in fasta format ---'
print

filepathProvided = False
#raw_input received the user input as string
try:
    filepath = raw_input('Enter filepath to save sequences ... ')
    filepath = filepath + '.fasta'
    handle = open(filepath, "w")
    handle.close()

    filepathProvided = True
except IOError:
    print 'Invalid or No File provided will print results to console'
print
ranSeqCount = 10
try:
    ranSeqCount = int(raw_input('Enter number of random sequences to generate ... '))
except ValueError:
    ranSeqCount = 10
pass

if(filepathProvided):
    handle = open(filepath, "w")

if(filepathProvided):
    fasta_writer = Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta.WriteFasta(handle)
else:
    fasta_writer = Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta.WriteFasta(stdout)
print 'Sequence Count : '
print ranSeqCount

for i in range(0,ranSeqCount,1):
    fasta_writer.write(randomProteinSeqRecord(i+1))
if(filepathProvided):
    handle.close()
print 'File created at : ' + filepath

print
raw_input('Press any key to exit ...')
print
```

Getting this ERROR:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hemant\Desktop\RandonProteinSequences.py", line 10, in 
    import Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta
ImportError: No module named writers.SeqRecord.fasta**

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. For code that isn't working such as yours please use stackoverflow. This site is for improving working code.

Comment: This might be better on StackOverflow. AIUI this site is for reviewing working code to suggest improvements, not fixing non-working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already mentioned this in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6056675/400127) and I'll say it here again:
This code is in need of an update, since [Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta is deprecated](http://python-biopython.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.49-1ubuntu1/namespaceBio_1_1writers_1_1SeqRecord_1_1fasta.html).

I took a quick look at Biopython's documentation trying to figure out how you can write a FASTA file.
Try this:

```
# File Name RandonProteinSequences.py
# standard library
import os
import random

# biopython
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio import SeqIO
from sys import *

residueList1 = ["C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
residueList2 = ["A","K","L","M","N","S"]
residueList3 = ["P","Q","R","T","V","W","Y"]
residueList4 = ["C","A","G","U"]

def getProteinSeqRecord(residue, seqcount):
    strSeq = ""
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        index = random.randint(0, len(residue)-1)
        strSeq += residue[index]

    sequence = Seq(strSeq, IUPAC.IUPACProtein)
    seqRec = SeqRecord(sequence, id = 'randSeq' + str(seqcount), description= 'A random sequence using Amino acid residues.')
    return seqRec

def getProteinSequence(residue):
    strSeq = ""
    for i in range(0,100,1):
        index = random.randint(0, len(residue)-1)
        strSeq += residue[index]

    sequence = Seq(strSeq, IUPAC.IUPACProtein)
    return sequence

def randomProteinSeqRecord(index):
    if(index%2)==0:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList1, index)
    elif(index%3)==0:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList2, index)
    else:
        return getProteinSeqRecord(residueList3, index)

#information
print '--- This is python based program to generate random sequences ---'
print '--- Provide number of random sequences to generate. Default 10 ---'
print '--- Inorder to save to a file provide file path or filename ---'
print '--- If none or invalid filepath is provided then results will be displayed to console ---'
print '--- The file will be created in fasta format ---'
print

filepathProvided = False
#raw_input received the user input as string
try:
    filepath = raw_input('Enter filepath to save sequences ... ')
    filepath = filepath + '.fasta'
    #handle = open(filepath, "w")
    #handle.close()

    filepathProvided = True
except IOError:
    print 'Invalid or No File provided will print results to console'
print
ranSeqCount = 10
try:
    ranSeqCount = int(raw_input('Enter number of random sequences to generate ... '))
except ValueError:
    ranSeqCount = 10
    pass

print 'Sequence Count : '
print ranSeqCount

records = []
for i in range(0,ranSeqCount,1):
    records.append(randomProteinSeqRecord(i+1))

if(filepathProvided):
    SeqIO.write(records, filepath, "fasta")
    print 'File created at : ' + filepath

else:
    print 'Writing to console is actually not supported!  :/'

print
raw_input('Press any key to exit ...')
print
```

Please note: I don't have Biopython installed, so I didn't run this code.
I'm trying to help you here, but the truth is I've got better things to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to change:

```
import Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta
```

for:

```
from Bio.writers.SeqRecord import fasta
```

Comment: do u mean [import Bio.writers.SeqRecord.fasta] TO 
[from Bio.writers.SeqRecord import fasta]
OR??

Comment: Similar... ImportError: No module named writers.SeqRecord

Comment: The Bio.writers bit of Biopython was deprecated and removed years ago - you want Bio.SeqIO instead as in other (accepted) answer.